# React js - How can a state be equal to each of the values of array?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem and my problem is I can't make my state equal to the values of the array.

What I want to happen is when the state value is equal to one of the values of the array the font color that will be printed should be red.

Here's my code

```
const arrayValues = [2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15];

<span style={{color: `${stateValue[i] === arrayValues} ? 'red' : ''`}}>
      {stateValue[i]}
</span>
```

So for example if the stateValue[i] === 2 then the font color should be red.

the value of stateValue comes from the other component that generate a random number. Can you suggest steps that needed to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to specify an index for `arrayValues` in your conditional. Right now you are comparing a single integer to an array. If you want you can see if the `arrayValues.indexOf(stateValue[i]) > -1` which means that the element does exist in the array or use `.includes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to happen is when the state value is equal to one of the values of the array

You may want to use [#Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
<span
  style={{
    color: `${arrayValues.includes(stateValue[i]) ? 'red' : 'none'}`
  }}
>
  {stateValue[i]}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:-

```
<span style={{color: `${arrayValues.some(i=> stateValue.includes(i))} ? 'red' : ''`}}>
      {stateValue[i]}
</span>
```